# django message files work in project folder but doesn't work in app folder

Tags: django, file, locale, message

I am testing django system and I started a project and a app for it. I have a problem with i18n system.

- I have used _() function in app's view.py.
- I put the 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware' line in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in project's settings.py file.
- I run django-admin.py makemessages -l tr in app folder.
- I run django-admin.py compilemessages in app folder.

When I run the service it didn't work. After I search in here and some other places I see the way how django looking these message files. First it looks app's folder, after project's folder. There are another places as well.

I moved my message files in project's folder and it worked. I moved the locale folder in app's folder again and it didn't work again.

I need to understand why. I want every translations, message files in releated app.

Regards,

---

I found the problem, I forgot to add the app name to INSTALLED_APPS settings. When I added, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it for myself and found it working.

Are you sure you use it in code in right way?

app/views.py:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.contrib import messages
...some code here...
if saved_changes:
  messages.success(request, _('Item \'%s\' was saved.') % item.name)
```

Comment: It worked when locale folder in project folder but when I moved the locale folder in the app folder, it doesn't work. 

This doesn't work: ./project_name/app_name/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po and .mo

This work:
./project_name/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po and .mo

Everything is the same. I just move the folder.

Comment: I think, that you can't move locale files. You need to generate locales again separately for app and project.

Try to delete from ./project/app/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/ directory .po and .mo files and try to go in app directory and `django-admin.py makemessages -l tr`

Then open _./project/app/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po_ file in translation software, like Lokalize or POEdit, translate all strings. Save changes and return to your app's directory and run `django-admin.py compilemessages`